# Why is this false?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

`In[1]:= TrueQ[Gamma[2 z] == (2^(2 z) Gamma[z] Gamma[z + 1/2])/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]])]`

`Out[1]:= False`

Can someone explain why the above is returning false?

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDuplicationFormula.html

I don't know what to tag this as, so I chose simplifying expressions.

Comment: ``Developer`GammaSimplify[
 Gamma[2 z] == (2^(2 z) Gamma[z] Gamma[z + 1/2])/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]])]`` gives `True`.

Comment: so does ``Simplify`SimplifyGamma[
 Gamma[2 z] == (2^(2 z) Gamma[z] Gamma[z + 1/2])/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]])]``.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The argument of `TrueQ` doesn't evaluate to `True`. It does if you wrap `FullSimplify` around it:

```
TrueQ[Gamma[2 z] == (2^(2 z) Gamma[z] Gamma[z + 1/2])/(2 Sqrt[π]) // FullSimplify]
```

> True

Comment: What would be nice is if it did evaluate to True without having to do that.... But algebraic simplification is hard for computers, so I'll let it slide.

Comment: @JackLam - Mathematica does not do much more than trivial simplification unless directed to do so. Consequently, your argument to `TrueQ` is not **"explicitly True"** and, as documented, `TrueQ` returns `False`.  Once you `FullSimplify`, `TrueQ` is unnecessary since `Gamma[2 z] == (2^(2 z) Gamma[z] Gamma[z+1/2])/(2 Sqrt[Pi])//FullSimplify` evaluates to `True`.